# Split data frame by delimiter rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame looks like:

```
   X1   X2   X3
1 ### <NA> <NA>
2  aa   bb   cc
3  dd   ee   ff
4 ### <NA> <NA>
5  a1   a2   a3
6  b1   b2   b3
7  g3   h3   k5
8 ### <NA> <NA>
9  k1   k2   k3
```

Is there a way to split it into a list of 3 small data.frame by the ### rows to:

```
[[1]]
   X1   X2   X3
1  aa   bb   cc
2  dd   ee   ff
[[2]]
1  a1   a2   a3
2  b1   b2   b3
3  g3   h3   k5  
[[3]]
1  k1   k2   k3
```

Thanks!

The code to generate the example df:

```
df=data.frame(rbind(c("###",NA,NA),c("aa","bb","cc"),c("dd","ee","ff"),c("###",NA,NA),c("a1","a2","a3"),c("b1","b2","b3"),c("g3","h3","k5"),c("###",NA,NA),c("k1","k2","k3")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `split` after creating a grouping variable using logical `vector`

```
i1 <- df$X1 == "###"
split(df[!i1,], cumsum(i1)[!i1])
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, akrun!

Answer (score 3):

Group the rows using `g` which is 1 for the rows in the first data frame, 2 for the rows in the second and so on.  Then split by `g` and remove the first row in each component.

```
g <- cumsum(df$X1 == "###")
lapply(split(df, g), tail, -1)
```

giving:

```
$`1`
  X1 X2 X3
2 aa bb cc
3 dd ee ff

$`2`
  X1 X2 X3
5 a1 a2 a3
6 b1 b2 b3
7 g3 h3 k5

$`3`
  X1 X2 X3
9 k1 k2 k3
```

Alternately the last line of code could be replaced with (which produces a `by` list):

```
by(df, g, tail, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
from <- which(df[,"X1"]=="###")+1
to <- c(tail(from,-1)-2, nrow(df))
mapply(function(a,b) df[a:b,], from, to, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

You would need to check for corner case (e.g. what if the first row is not `###` or if the last row has `###`).